# Symfony event listener after save new entity

Tags: symfony

I need check if entity is instance of specific entity and do something after save new entity. Something like method afterSave in cakephp. I tried `postFlush`, `onFlush`, `postPersist` and `postLoad`.

AppBundle/EventListener/DoSomethingAfterSaveNewEntity.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity;

class DoSomethingAfterSaveNewEntity 
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {   
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        if (!$entity instanceof SomeEntity) {
          die('not instance!!!');
        }

        die('post flush!!!');
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea is right, but you should create a new EntityListener or EntitySubscriber for that. So not the entity itself listens to its changes (bad practice).

`services.yml`:

```
your.entity.subscriber:
      class: AppBundle\Subscriber\YourEntitySubscriber
      tags:
          - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

`YourEntitySubscriber.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Subscriber;

use AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class YourEntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postPersist',
            'postUpdate',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // Do whatever you want (after entity creation)
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Also you can get more examples here: [event_listeners_subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)